# Add a field to a model in Django without having to delete the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-database

I would like to add a field to a model in Django. However, when I do this I get the following error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: . I know I can fix this by deleting the database and running migrations, but is there a way to do it without having to delete the database? It is a lot of work to put all the data in there again every time I want to add a field to a model.

Running migrations and deleting the migration files does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess up a lot. It's easy, after any change in model just run these commands

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: When I run 'python manage.py makemigrations', I get this error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column

Comment: I can alter fields and add models and it's all fine, but as soon as I want to add a field to a model, it gives this error. Very frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

If you have runned the commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and
`python manage.py migrate` and you have mistakenly bypass the migration file that added the field, you can check your database, under the table `django_migrations` you can delete the record where the migration file created the column and run the command `python manage.py migrate` again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I have a modelform that depends on the CsvCreate model, which is why the migrations would not run:

```
parameters = CsvCreate.objects.values().latest('uploaded')['parameters']
```

When I commented it out and ran the migrations everything worked.